# Looking for possible subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am looking to enumerate subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that meet the following constraint

- If $x_1=0$ then $x_i=0 \hspace{2mm}\forall \hspace{2mm} i=2,\cdots,n$.

Any possibilities?

Comment: It is subspaces which trivially intesects with subspace $x_1=0$, can you say something about dimension of such subspace?

Comment: Dimension can be 1,2,..,n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspace $x_1 = 0$ has dimension $n-1$, and therefore must have nontrivial intersection with any subspace of dimension $\geq 2$.

Hence the required subspaces are $\{0\}$ and all lines not contained in the hyperplane $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain your answer when n=2, n=3. I am trying to get a geometric interpretation of your answer but not really getting there.

Comment: for n=2, the only subspace is {0}?

Comment: For $n = 2$, the answer is $\{0\}$ or any line other than the line $x_1 = 0$. For $n = 3$, the answer is $\{0\}$ or any line not contained in the plane $x_1 = 0$.